# Unix Executable File to OSX .App?

Tags: c++, macos, sfml, .app

I made a simple SFML app in Xcode with some icons, pictures, music, etc. that I can run from the command line if I'm in the directory with its associated parts. I don't know anything about OSX development, but is there any simple way to package the executable file and its dependencies so it runs as a .app program? Would someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is no such thing as UNIX executable file. There is a HPUX executable file, Linux executable file... and Mac executable file (Mac OS X being a certified UNIX). No, you cannot use a Linux ELF file on Mac OS X, except under an emulator. However, SFML home page claims it is multiplatform - so just compile your source on a Mac. EDIT: oops, the Mac platform is not available at the moment.

Comment: I was just reading under Get Info, Type: Unix Executable File. I'm a beginner at programming and I wanted to know if I could somehow attach the dependencies to the executable and turn it into an app to distribute/run more easily.

Comment: It would be like shouting in Navajo and expecting a Russian to understand you. You can't run a Linux binary executable on a Mac.

Comment: I didn't realize that it wasn't compatible in this way since I created it with Xcode. It compiles with g++ on my mac, but I have to run it from command line instead of being able to just add it to my dock and double click on it.

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood your question. If you compiled it on a Mac, then it should be able to run. It's just that the question was quite unclear, since many things can be called "UNIX executable" (and the most common of them being Linux ELF). [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html) you can see how an App bundle should look like.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was trying to find

Comment: This is explained in the getting started tutorial for Xcode. We also provide a template to make such .app easily for SFML. Did you read that? http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-osx.php